# Register TYPO3 Dashboard widget without making TYPO3 Dashboard mandatory in TYPO3 11

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I'm trying to provide a widget for the TYPO3 Dashboard in TYPO3 11.
I'm registering the widget in `Configuration/Services.yaml` in my extension, but I don't want to require the Dashboard extension, just suggest it via `suggests` in `composer.json`.

However, the CMS complains about `WidgetInterface` not present on an installation without `typo3/cms-dashboard` required in `composer.json`.

The error message:
[image: Dashboard error message]

How do I register a widget but not make the TYPO3 Dashboard mandatory to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could register it in `Configuration/Services.php` instead and check first whether the `WidgetInterface` is loaded.

Then, do not register it if the interface does not exist.

[Official Documentation](https://github.com/TYPO3-CMS/dashboard/blob/master/Documentation/Configuration/WidgetRegistration.rst#servicesphp-file)

Comment: See https://github.com/georgringer/doc/blob/master/Configuration/Services.php for an example

Comment: Well I found my answer in the dashboard documentation. Could you expand your answer @Daniel and refer to this and what class to check via `$container->hasDefinition()`? https://github.com/TYPO3-CMS/dashboard/blob/master/Documentation/Configuration/WidgetRegistration.rst#servicesphp-file